# How to link to a text area using a clickable image icon

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a webpage which contains clickable image icons of some companies (eg. the logo of Mercedes Benz). When this icon is clicked, a text area appears on the same page (while the background is blurred out) and a user of this webpage can enter his comments about the company into the text area. I have searched long and hard about how to write a HTML code that produces this scenario, but have not been able to find anything. Can anyone help? I do not think that my code below is anywhere near what I need.

```
          <form method="post" action="<?php echo         
             htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

          <a href="mercedes"><img src="Mercedes logo.jpg"
             alt="Daimler Benz" width="72" height="46" border="0" /></a>
          <input type="text" name="mercedes"><br/>

          </form>
```

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: I would look into javascript modals (for example http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: You should use javascript for this. I would suggesting using Bottstraps modal which would be perfect for what you need i think. Here are some expamples of it, and explaination how to implement it http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Liam, rwacarter, and Chilipepper, I want to thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve most of what you want without using Javascript. Instead of an anchor, use a `label`, so you can work with `:focus`:

```css
label img {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  }
label img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1);
}
input[type='text'] {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
input[type='text']:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label for="mercedes">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/abstract/3">
</label>
<label for="porsche">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/abstract/5">
</label>
<br />
<input type="text" id="mercedes" placeholder="Mercedes" />
<input type="text" id="porsche" placeholder="Porsche" />
```

Comment: connexo, I'm glad you showed me how to achieve my objective WITHOUT having to use JavaScript because JS is my weakest point. I try to avoid using JS whenever I can. I am very, very grateful to you for showing me how to do it using just HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using javascript, on the click event of the link focus on the text input:

```js
function linktoText(){
 var text=document.getElementById("mercedes");
    text.focus();
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="<?php echo         
             htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

          <a id="myLink" onclick="linktoText()" ><img src="Mercedes logo.jpg"
             alt="Daimler Benz" width="72" height="46" border="0" /></a>
          <input type="text" name="mercedes" id="mercedes"><br/>

          </form>
```

**EDIT:**

And [**this is a Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jbvw4e59/1/) that shows a textarea by clicking the link.

Comment: chsdk, I can't thank you enough. Your code is exactly what I've been looking for. I'm much obliged.

Comment: @Jason12 Look at the fiddle on my EDIT, you will find how to show a textarea by clicking on link.

Comment: Just tried out the Fiddle, it's very useful. JavaScript is my weakest point, and I'm brushing up on it. But pointers like yours are very helpful and speeds up my learning process. Gave you a tick up!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in javascript 
here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/PrakharThakur/0kdvunmx/

```js
$('#img').click(function() {
  $('#container').fadeIn(300);
});

$('#close').click(function() {
  $('#container').fadeOut(300);
});
```

```css
 #container {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #aaa;
   text-align: center;
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   z-index: 100;
   opacity: 0.7;
 }
 #img {
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 #close {
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img">click me</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="box">What do you Think about merce?
    <form>
      <input type="text"></input>
      <br>
      <input type="submit"></input>
      <div id="close">close</div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Prakhar, that is a very comprehensive and extremely useful piece of code. I'm so grateful for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Just to mention that it's jQuery and not Javascript.

Comment: yeah i know, jQuery itself is written in javascript, anyway, you are welcome. :)